# Implementación de Multiplicación rusa

Tags: java, matemáticas

aqui esta un ejemplo de multiplicacion rusa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

trata de que el primer numero vaya reduciendoce en su divisible mas proximo y el otro numero vaya aumentando multiplicado por su divisible mas proximo

mi codigo, estoy iniciando con programacion y debo hacer la multiplicacion como multiplican los rusos. pero no funciona

```
public int Multi_Rusa(int a..., int b){
    int c=0;
    while(a!=0){
        if(as % 2 != 0){
            c = c + b;
        }
        a = as / 2;
        b = b * 2;
    } 
    return c;
}
```

Comment: de donde sale `as`? por qué es multiplicacion rusa?

Comment: Sería bueno que explicaras el método que sigue la multiplicación rusa ya que con el dibujo no queda del todo claro.

Comment: Y además, cuando digas, "no funciona", pon un ejemplo explicando el "no funciona" (he hecho `Multi_Rusa(5, 20)` y me devuelve `69`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que tienes errores en tu codigo 
en la

> firma de tu funcion pusiste "..." el cual representa un array

e hiciste apareces como arte de magia la variable "ass"

intenta probando con estas modificaciones:

```
public int Multi_Rusa(int a, int b){
    int c=0;
    while(a!=0){
        if(a % 2 != 0){
            c = c + b;
        }
        a = a / 2;
        b = b * 2;
    } 
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes una variable `as` que sería `b`  y las operaciones que haces con `b` sería para `a`

```
  public static int Multi_Rusa(int a, int b){
   int c=0;
   while(a!=0){
    if(b % 2 != 0){
        c = c + a;
     }
      b = b / 2;
      a = a * 2;
    } 
     return c;
  }
```